# Почему в мониторе порта Arduino пишет "esp8266/Arduino CI has failed"?

Tags: arduino

Написал скетч для отправки данных с датчика температуры в Google Таблицы. Данные отправляются, всё работает, но в мониторе порта выводит "esp8266/Arduino CI has failed" вместо "esp8266/Arduino CI successfull!". Кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Код Arduino:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h> //Библиотека для работы модуля Wi-Fi
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include "DHT.h" //Библиотека для работы датчика DHT-11

//Создание объектов dht с параметрами пина подключения и типа датчиков.
//Объект dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE) класса DHT.
DHT dht1(D3, DHT11);

//Настройки Wi-Fi.
char ssid[] = "..."; //Имя сети
char pass[] = "..."; //Пароль сети. Нет пароля - ""

const char* host = "script.google.com"; //хост
const int httpsPort = 443; //порт

WiFiClientSecure client;

const char* fingerprint = "..."; //отпечаток SHA-256
String GAS_ID = "...";

void setup() {
  //Старт передачи данных в монитор порта.
  //Используется при отладке кода.
  Serial.begin(115200);
  dht1.begin(); //инициализация работы датчиков

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}


void loop() {
  float t = dht1.readTemperature();
  int h = dht1.readHumidity();
  if (isnan(t) || isnan(h)) {
    Serial.println("Failed to read from DHT sensor !");
    delay(500);
    return;
  }
  Serial.println("=================================");
  String Temp = "Temperature : " + String(t) + " °C";
  String Humi = "Humidity : " + String(h) + " %";
  Serial.println(Temp);
  Serial.println(Humi);
  sendData(t,h);
}


void sendData(float t, int h) //функция отправки get запроса
{
  client.setInsecure(); //подключение к хосту
  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);
  if (!client.connect(host,httpsPort)) { //сообщение при неудаче
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }
  String string_temperature =  String(t);
  String string_humidity =  String(h);
  String url = "/macros/s/" + GAS_ID + "/exec?temperature=" + string_temperature + 
 "&humidity=" + string_humidity; //составляем ссылку со значениями
  Serial.print("requesting URL: "); //сообщение ссылки
  Serial.println(url);

  client.print(String("GET ") + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
              "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
              "User-Agent: BuildFailureDetectorESP8266\r\n" +
              "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");

  Serial.println("request sent"); //сообщение об отправке запроса
  while (client.connected()) {
    String line = client.readStringUntil('\n'); //считать ответ
    if (line == "\r") {
      Serial.println("headers received"); //сообщение о получении ответа
      break;
    }
  }
  String line = client.readStringUntil('\n');
  if (line.startsWith("{\"state\":\"success\"")) {
    Serial.println("esp8266/Arduino CI successfull!");
  } else {
    Serial.println("esp8266/Arduino CI has failed");
    }
  Serial.println("reply was: ");
  Serial.println(line);
  Serial.println("closing connection");
}
```

[image: Код Google Script]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Пишет потому что не срабатывает условие `if (line.startsWith("{\"state\":\"success\"")) {`. Почему не срабатывает, это нужно вам выяснять.